# Why Shell_exec() and exec() not working in php? $return_val is 0

Tags: php, terminal, cron, exec, shell-exec

```
file_put_contents('/opt/lampp/htdocs/imslivedec/crontab.txt','0 11 15 1 * /opt/lampp/htdocs/imslivedec/sendmail.php'.PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
shell_exec('crontab /opt/lampp/htdocs/imslivedec/crontab.txt');
```

When I run this exact same command in the terminal, the new cron job is getting 
created but when I do from the php script using shell_exec() the command is not executing in the terminal.May I know why, am I doing anything wrong here?The shell_ exec works fine when I tried to create a new folder.

Comment: Is the behaviour specific to cron? How do you execute it? Also, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hello, I'm new to the cronjob and linux, So I'm bit unaware of all these.Here, I want to schedule a cronjob dynamically from my php script by creating a new text file and writing a command in it and trying to execute it.The text file has been created but I think my program not able to execute it because I'm unable to see any new cronjobs in the terminal.

Is the behaviour specific to cron?
I never tried with other,my aim here is to just schedule cron dynamically.

How do you execute it?
Just as a normal php script,executing in the browser.

Hope you got my problem,thankyou.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify it. Still, you don't have an MCVE here. Also, it would be interesting to know whether it's just editing the crontab that doesn't work. The idea is to reduce the issue as much as possible. Further, instead of running it in the webserver (not in the browser as you write!) but on the commandline also decreases the scope.

Comment: I've edited the question and stated my issue as much as I can. I hope you can understand the issue now.

Comment: I do understand the issue. However, *you* need to reduce its scope now. There are many questions open and you still haven't provided a [mcve] yet. Actually, adding a DB query to your code makes it even less possible to verify (the "V" in MCVE) the issue.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I figured out few things and now left only with this question,could you please look at the question again.

Comment: @SrikarReddy, 1. How do you run the php file, from a CLI or a browser?   2. Use `exec` instead of `shell_exec` to get more information then post here.

Comment: @shingo I'm running the file from the browser and tried `exec` but nothing happens.

Comment: @SrikarReddy What means nothing happens? the output is empty and the exit code is 0?

Comment: "The shell_ exec works fine when I tried to create a new folder." -- you mean when you were calling `/bin/mkdir`? Or when invoking `mkdir()` from PHP? Just a note for further questions: "works fine" is an interpretation, but the lack of the observation forces me to guess. Anyhow, assuming `/bin/mkdir`, the difference between that an `/usr/bin/crontab` is that the latter is a SGID executable that's started with additional privileges. I would hope that the webserver environment disables that for safety reasons. Also, it probably runs as a different user (does it?).

Comment: @shingo as you said I used  `exec('crontab /opt/lampp/htdocs/imslivedec/crontab.txt 2>&1',$output);`
   `print_r($output);` instead of shell_exec and the output was an empty array.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I used `shell_exec('mkdir folder_name')` to create a folder but with a lock symbol on the folder I don't know what that means.You said that webserver disabled from running this command, so can't we run this command from the browser in any way?

Comment: @SrikarReddy please also check the 3rd argument $return_var.

Comment: @shingo I checked $return_var also, it returned the value 0. can we get any information from that?

Comment: after that command I also executed `shell_exec('crontab -l')` and it returned all the cronjobs I've added, doesn't that mean it executed correctly in the browser?

Comment: @SrikarReddy It means the command is sucessfully executed.

Comment: then how come it is not executing in the terminal? am I missing any point here?

Comment: do you think any privileges restricting me from executing the command in terminal?is there a chance?

Comment: @SrikarReddy, Why are you think the command is not executed? As you said above, `crontab -l` shows that the job is already added into crontab right?

Comment: @shingo that's because when I go to the terminal and look at the list of cronjob's,the recent cronjob is not added, but If I enter the same command in the terminal the it executes perfectly and add the cronjob to the list.

Comment: @SrikarReddy notice there is one crontab for each user, and usually PHP is running by a user that is different with the login user. Check this by `crontab -lu <user_name>`.

Comment: @shingo You are right,the command is executing in the other user's crontab. So I used this `cat /etc/passwd | sed 's/^\([^:]*\):.*$/echo "\ncrontab for \1:"; sudo crontab -u \1 -l 2>\&1/' | grep -v "no crontab for" | sh` to find out the user name,after knowing it I used `sudo crontab -l -u daemon` to get the cronjobs list